# Upload file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file-upload

I am trying to upload file using angularJS. The problem is I would like to follow good practices and use code like this in my controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.uploadFile = uploadFile;
```

But it makes hard for me to upload files, because every answer I found is based on $scope and I can not modify it to make it work with vm.

How can I make following code work with vm?

```
<input type="file" name="file"  onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)">
```

In my controller.js

```
 function uploadFile(files) {
    //working code proccessing file
  };
```

How can I make provided html work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a ready-made boilerplate, like `ng-file-upload`. In our project it works like a charm:

**Npm**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-upload

**Demo**

https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/